# Explanation of empty strings syntax ""

Tags: java

I cant understand `String tabell = "";` why?`""`

and I can't understand the following: `tabell = tabell + i + " " + i*i + "`

File Tab.java

```
public class Tab {
 public static void main (String[] arg) {
   String tabell = "";
    for (int i=1; i<=12; i++)
     tabell = tabell + i + "   " + i*i + "   " + i*i*i + " ";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tabell);
     }
}
```

Comment: what dose that mean?String tabell = "";            and how is working?tabell = tabell + i + "   " + i*i + "   " + i*i*i + " ";          and i know how for() working but...

Comment: You are creating a `String` by concatenating a `String` with a number `int`...

Comment: Means that you initialize the variable with empty string !!

Comment: `Java` will do some simple conversions for you like concatenating a `String` and a number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String tabell = "";` is needed to even create a String object. (otherwise `tabell` would be `null`.

`i*i` is the same as `i^2` and `i*i*i` = `i^3`

`tabell = tabell + i + "   " + i*i + "   " + i*i*i + " ";`

Essentially it appends this to the already existing `String` in `tabell`:

```
(i = 1, first for iteration)
1   1   1 
(i = 2, second for iteration)
2   4   8 
(i = 3, third for iteration)
3   9   27 
etc...
```

So after 3 iterations of the for loop your String will be:

`1   1   1 2   4   8 3   9   27`

Finally, after the loop a `MessageDialog` is shown with the current `tabell` contents with:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tabell);
```

Comment: i got this ,thank you so so so much

Comment: @MohammadAZare np, happy to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how your method would be read:

```
public class Tab {
     public static void main (String[] arg) {
         String tabell = "";//A string object

         for (int i=1; i<=12; i++)//Call the statement below 12 times.
             tabell = tabell + i + "   " + i*i + "   " + i*i*i + " ";
             //concate the tabell string with what comes after the '=' 

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tabell);//Display the tabell string in an option pane
    }
}
```

I presume the line your having trouble with is: `tabell = tabell + i + "   " + i*i + "   " + i*i*i + " ";`

What your doing here is adding the number `i` to your string object multiple times, both in the for loop and the line of code itself.